# How can I play the audio successively with PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have several `Media` file to play. But they have to be played one by one.
like:

```
var play_media;
play_media= new Media("../record/01.mp3",Success,Error);
play_media.play();
//And as the `../record/01.mp3` media file is done. 
//I will release it and create another one to play. 
play_media= new Media("../record/02.mp3",Success,Error);
```

But it seems that as one media's play is done, it returns nothing. 

How can I do ?

Comment: *mediaSuccess: (Optional) The callback that is invoked after a Media object has completed the current play/record or stop action.* This can be trigger to play next song

Comment: Do you mean Media(,,,"mediaSuccess")? I'll study on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var media = {"../record/01.mp3","../record/02.mp3","../record/03.mp3"};
var next = 0, play_media;
for(int i=0; i<media.lenght; i++){
    play_media= new Media(media[next]);
    play_media.play();
    if(soundTimer == null){
        soundTimer = setInterval(function(){
            vpSound.getCurrentPosition(
                function(position){
                    if(position > -1){
                        //Do something if you want 
                    }
                }
            );
        }, 1000);
        next = next + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First find the audio clip length with media.getDuration:
and use setTimeout Function to play next song.
In this way you will be able play multiple songs continuously

Answer (score 0):

Use the Media.getCurrentPosition() along with the javascript setInterval and set it to  interval every second (1000) to get the position of the track being played.Then check if the position of the track is equal to -0.001 and this means that it has ended. From there you can move onto the next track or if it is the last track use Media.release()

```
           var mediaTimer = setInterval(function () {
               media.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                     if (position > -0.001) {
                        //Do something like update a progress bar and set times.
                     }
                     else if (position === -0.001) {
                           selectedIndex = selectedIndex + 1; //selectedIndex is the index of the song chosen in a list.
                          if (selectedIndex > playlistLength) {
                              media.release();
                          } 
                          else {
                            var nextTrack = app.FolderList.tracks[selectedIndex]; //get the next track from a list of tracks using the selectedIndex
                            playPause(nextTrack.SongPath);//playPause() is used to initialize a new Media object with the new track and then plays it.
                          }
                     },
                     function () {
                     console.log('Unable to retrieve media position: ' + error.code);
                       });
                    },
                    1000);
```